# How much autocorrelation in errors is too much?

Tags: time-series, p-value, autocorrelation

When working with time series data, one does not want autocorrelation in errors. After running the Portmanteau Test on a time series, I obtain a p-value of 5.8%. Increasing a lag yields a p-value of 7.4%.

I am curious, from a practitioner's perspective, would the 5.8% (or 7.4%) case be seen as "OK" since we cannot reject the null of no autocorrelation at the 5% level? I am curious about where one should draw the line.

Comment: It would be more useful to tell us the values of the autocorrelation. Why don't you want autocorrelation? Most time series have this and it makes forecasting easier.

Comment: Oh dear, I forgot to add what autocorrelation, thanks for pointing that out. I'm sorry about that, I edited my question. It refered to the autocorrelation in the errors.